# Is this error occur because of any code mistake or is it something to do with ballerina server?

Tags: wso2, ballerina, wso2-choreo

My code ran successfully until now. But after some time, when I run it, I receive this error: What's the solution? Is it due to a coding error or a ballerina server error?
I coudn't figure it out.

```
import ballerinax/mysql;
import ballerinax/mysql.driver as _;
import ballerina/http;
import ballerina/log;
import ballerina/sql;

configurable int port = ?;
configurable string database = ?;
configurable string password = ?;
configurable string user = ?;
configurable string host = ?;

type output record {
  boolean valid;
  boolean isGuilty?;
  string charges?;
};

type Person record {
  string nic;
  @sql:Column {name: "isguilty"}
  int isGuilty;
  string charges?;
};

mysql:Client mysqlEp = check new (host = host, user = user, password = password, database =database, port = port);

# A service representing a network-accessible API
# bound to port `9090`.
service / on new http:Listener(9090) {

   //function for checking the police records by nic
   resource function get policeCheck/[string nic]() returns output|error? {
       Person|error queryRowResponse=mysqlEp->queryRow(`select * from police_details where nic=${nic.trim()}`);

       if queryRowResponse is error{
          output result={
              valid: false
          };
          log:printInfo("Invalid NIC");
          return result;
      }else{
          Person person=queryRowResponse;
          if person.isGuilty==0{
              output result={
                  valid: true,
                  isGuilty: false
              };
              log:printInfo(result.toBalString());
              return result;
          }else if person.isGuilty==1 {
              output result={
                  valid: true,
                  isGuilty: true,
                  charges:<string>person.charges
              };
              log:printInfo(result.toBalString());
              return result;
          }

    
      }
      return;
  }
}
```

The following are the images that shows the error that shows in commandline.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ri3c.png)

[error image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNxAK.png)

Comment: This is not an issue with your code, but an issue in the Choreo.

Comment: This is raised in https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-lang/issues/34926.